# Visual C++ /HEAP Linker-Option

Tags: visual-c++, linker, heap-memory

I currently have some trouble with the Heap in a program of mine. While I was googling my way through the internet to find solutions I came across a page from the MSDN that describes some linker options for heap allocation that I don't understand.

[The documentation says that you can set the Heapsize with /HEAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90ybzkh%28VS.80%29.aspx).

I always knew that the stack size was fixed and that makes sense to me. But I always thought that the Heap is variable in size. To add some more confusion I found that the default value is 1MB. I have written lots of programs that use more than 1 MB of memory.

What exactly does the /HEAP Option do then?

Thanks

Comment: Before we dive into fiddling with deep interna and questioning an intelligent compiler's sensible defaults, would you mind telling us what "some trouble" was?

Comment: Here is the question about my heap trouble: http://goo.gl/KYMRj
However I would like to understand how it works so I can maybe avoid similar problems in the future.

Comment: It's impossible to tell where that's coming from, since you're just using an external function call that could have done all sorts of shenanigans. Post a complete, minimal, self-contained example if you can so we can focus on something manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

windows gives .exes (processes) memory by giving them read/write acess to pages of memory.  To the C++ programmer, it should be left to the operating system, never to be messed with

/HEAP 1,000,000 means that an .exe starts up with 1,000,000 bytes worth of pages... TO START WITH.  Changing this value shouldn't affect anything.  Windows automatically pages in memory.  It's just a hint for windows to give this process the memory it needs for performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the OS heap (`HeapAlloc` function) which is controlled by the PE header, in turn set by this linker option, and your C++ runtime library dynamic allocation (`malloc`, `new`) which probably grab memory directly from the OS using `VirtualAlloc` and don't use the OS heap.

For more information on the OS heap parameters, read the MSDN documentation for [`CreateHeap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366599.aspx).